# R - use slots of a class or arguments of function as slots to another class

Tags: r, class

Is there a way, in R, to get the slots of a class, e.g. A, or the arguments of a function, e.g. foo, and use them as slots of class, e.g. B?

Example:

If class A, has slots -> test1="numeric", test2="numeric", 
function foo, has arguments -> x, y, 
I would like class B, to have slots -> test1="numeric", test2="numeric", x="numeric", y="numeric".

Comment: Have a look here https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/slot.html

Comment: Could you, please, provide an example of how this could be applied? If I get the slots of a class, how will they become the slots of another?

Comment: This should work `setClass("B", representation = as.list(getSlots("A")))`

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work with the classes. I was getting errors because I was adding the slots to the representation (representation(custom_a="numeric", as.list(getSlots("A")))) and not using "=".